# generally gets() takes the input as \n which is at the end of printf() above it

Tags: c, newline, fgets, gets

Why does gets() ask for string here. I mean, why doesn't it consume the newline character from the previous printf() and the program just terminate?
And yes i know i should use fgets() and stuff like that. Please don't mention about it.

code for reference-

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char str[30];
    printf("\n");
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
}
```

Comment: You assumptions are incorrect, gets() does not consume the output of a previous printf() statement. Please explain what you do, what happens, and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual of `char *gets(char *str)`:

> Reads a line from stdin and stores it into the string pointed to by,
>   str. It stops when either the newline character is read or when the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

From the manual for printf :

> The functions  printf()  and  vprintf()  write output  to stdout, the
>   standard output stream;

As the manual mentions, `gets` reads a line from `stdin`.

The function `printf` writes to `stdout`.

Therefore `gets` won't read what `printf` is writing.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("\n");` prints output to `stdout`. `gets(str)` reads input from `stdin`.

Further reference to [gets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm) and [printf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

Further reference to [stdin vs stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)